# BackboneJS root level views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, amd

If you have some root level HTML that is present on "almost" every screen, where/how would you organize this?

I'm using backbone-boilerplate and requirejs. One of the root level views is a global navigation element that can be invoked from the bottom of the screen at any time.

This is organized in a module that has a model (for visibility, the selected state, the log of clicks, etc). The app is stored in:

```
ClientName.app = _.extend( { rootViews: {} }, Backbone.Views);
```

Then in my routers initialize method, i have:

```
ClientName.app.rootViews.globalNav = new GlobalNav.Views.BottomView({ model: new GlobalNav.Models.Bottom()});
```

It works fine, but as the functionality is growing, the routers initialize method is getting out of hand with similar root views, sub routers, etc. Am I totally missing something?

What would you recommend?

Comment: Why not add the global nav to your layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out [Marionette.Region](http://derickbailey.github.com/backbone.marionette/#marionette-region)?  This allows you to assign views to specific divs, such as your footer.  You could define the body area of your app as another region that you can dynamically swap out when you navigate to different pages.

The Router is generally a poor choice for a View Controller.  Instead, I'd recommend checking out Marionette, which handles this kind of thing quite well.  You can implement your page navigation control using [application events](http://derickbailey.github.com/backbone.marionette/#marionette-eventaggregator), which you can wire up your main View to listen for, and then swap out Regions dynamically.  Check out the good example apps at the bottom of the Marionette docs for starting points.